# Getting maxCharsPerRecord: 1,048,576 in S3 in AWS S3 SelectObjectContent

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-s3-select

I am fetching records from the s3 JSON file using s3 select. Everything working for me when I fetch data from small JSON files ie 2MB(with record count around 10000)

> Following is my query

```
innerStart = 1
innerStop = 100
maximumLimit = 100
query = "SELECT * FROM s3object r where r.id > " + str(innerStart) + " and r.id <= " + str(innerStop) + " limit " + str(maximumLimit);
r = s3.select_object_content(
     Bucket=cache,
     Key= key + '.json',
     ExpressionType='SQL',
     Expression= query,
     InputSerialization={'JSON': {"Type": "Lines"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
     OutputSerialization={'JSON': {
     }},
)
```

But when I try to query some records from large JSON files (ie 100 MB over 578496 records). I am getting the following error. I tried changing my query to fetch an only a single record from a large JSON file also didn't work for me. Is there any Scan character limit for S3 Select?

> File "./app/main.py", line 118, in retrieve_from_cache_json
> OutputSerialization={'JSON': {   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 357,
> in _api_call
> return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 676,
> in _make_api_call
> raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name) botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (OverMaxRecordSize)
> when calling the SelectObjectContent operation: The character number
> in one record is more than our max threshold, maxCharsPerRecord:
> 1,048,576
>
> Sample JSON file

```
{
        "id": 1,
        "hostname": "registry.in.",
        "subtype": "A",
        "value": "5.9.139.185",
        "passive_dns_count": "4",
        "count_total": 11,
        "count": 11
    }
    {
        "id": 2,
        "hostname": "registry.ctn.in.",
        "subtype": "A",
        "value": "18.195.87.188",
        "passive_dns_count": "2",
        "count_total": 11,
        "count": 11
    }
    
        "id": 3,
        "hostname": "registry.in.",
        "subtype": "NS",
        "value": "ns-243.awsdns-30.com.",
        "passive_dns_count": "6",
        "count_total": 11,
        "count": 11
    }
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: I think you are hitting this limit: `The maximum length of a record in the input or result is 1 MB.`. How big are your records?

Comment: I am  sure it's not the result, because I tried fetching only a single record. Do you know what is "The maximum length of a record in the input". 

My json file has 578496 records, but I am limiting the record count as 100, but s3 cannot able to scan large JSON.

Comment: I changed the JSON schema to CSV and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my JSON schema to CSV, csv select worked for me. Following is my query

```
innerStop = 100
innerStart = 0
maximumLimit = 100
query = "SELECT * FROM s3Object r WHERE cast(r.\"id\" as float) > " + str(innerStart) + " and cast(r.\"id\" as float) <=" + str(innerStop) + " limit " + str(maximumLimit);
    r = s3.select_object_content(
         Bucket=cache,
         Key= 'filename' + '.csv',
         ExpressionType='SQL',
         Expression= query,
         InputSerialization = {'CSV': {"FileHeaderInfo": "Use"}, 'CompressionType': 'NONE'},
         OutputSerialization = {'CSV': {}},
    )
    for event in r['Payload']:
     if 'Records' in event:
         records = event['Records']['Payload'].decode('utf-8')
```